# Import existing git repository's folder into another git repository's subfolder

Tags: git

I am new to git. I have two repositories with a structure like this:

```
Repo1
  |- .git
  |- CCC

Repo2
  |- .git
  |- AAA
      |- BBB
          |- CCC
```

Problem is that in Repo2, I want to pull CCC folder from Repo1 and also ensure that in future, if there are any changes in CCC folder in Repo1, then I should be able to pull those changes to CCC Repo2. Can anybody help me with the procedure to achieve this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put the directory CCC into its own repository, and then use `git submodule` to add it back into Repo1 and Repo2.

You can extract CCC from Repo2 into its own repository with history using `git filter-branch`, if you need to preserve its history.

Comment: Or may be move the contents of CCC to main folder, delete CCC folder, rename Repo1 as CCC and then make submodule?